# Should I use Vuex Store + watch variable as a way to simulate event?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-events

Since I do not have a lot of experience in web development, I was wondering if this is a pattern or anti-pattern in Vue2.

1. Have a variable "callId" in Vuex store. By default it is empty.
2. When a call has arrived, set variable callId to the newly arrived call's id.
3. Any Vue Component interested in this event can map this variable from state and watch it -> when it changes to non empty value, it means there's a new call

This way events could be simulated via Vuex.
I thought of using event bus, but I've been told it is not recommended.

Comment: This seems to be a good strategy yes, advantage of using vueX is that you can call your variable very easily in any of your component, where an event bus need to be call in every hierarchical path...

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it is because I come from other languages, but this pattern is very weird to me since I thought store should be used for persistent values (for example: currentUser, list of contacts etc.). With this pattern variable is mostly sitting idle and has no meaning.

Comment: I actually use the vuex method in a dashboard where once the search Panel is complete, all data are sent to each one of my widget composing my dash. Be carefull ,I personnally sttrugle a bit at the beginning with concept of getter (declared function in store , but get data for component) but once you have experience with it it's all fun

Comment: it is the flux pattern